# How to write a test case for a function which gets another function as argument?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

```
const remove = (arr) => {
    return arr.splice(1 , 2);
}
const removeElement = (func , arr) => {
      return func(arr)
}
console.log(removeElement(remove , [1,2,3,4,5]));
```

In the above code I am passing remove function to removeElement function as an argument how can I write a test case for removeElement function? I don't want to write the entire remove function inside the test file.

Comment: removeElement is a bad name for the second function because that's **not** what it does in general. Its actual behaviour is calling whatever function it's provided with whatever value it's provided and returning the result, it only removes elements when it's called with remove and an array. That behaviour can be tested without recreating the specific function it happens to get called with.

Comment: ok while writing test case for removeElement function what do we pass the first argument  for function